# Как сделать удаление без перезагрузки, с помощью AJAX?

Tags: ajax, json

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Learn js</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="users" style="float: left;"></div>
  <button id="delete">Удалить юзера</button>

  <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

java script

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/users', false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
response = JSON.parse(response);

var usersDiv = document.getElementById('users');

for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  usersDiv.innerHTML += 'id '+ response[i].id + '<br>' + response[i].name + '<br>' + response[i].email + '<br>' + '<br>';
}

var deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete');
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var deleteUser = +prompt('id юзера для удаления', '');
  $.ajax(`http://localhost:3000/users/${deleteUser}`, {
    method: 'Delete'
  });
});
```

Когда делаю удаление, нужно перезагрузить страницу чтобы в dom удалился юзер, как это сделать без перезагрузки ?

Comment: Зачем эта мешанина синхронного `XMLHttpRequest`-а,  `addEventListener`-а и jQuery? Заворачивайте html для каждого пользователя в свой `div` с `id`, чтобы потом можно было этот `div` найти и удалить.

Comment: В чем проблема элемент удалить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не буду говорить, как лучше и т.п. как в комментариях, отвечу на твой вопрос - в js скрипте нужно добавить следующее

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/users', false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
response = JSON.parse(response);

var usersDiv = document.getElementById('users');

for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  usersDiv.innerHTML += 'id '+ response[i].id + '<br>' + response[i].name + '<br>' + response[i].email + '<br>' + '<br>';
}

var deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete');
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var deleteUser = +prompt('id юзера для удаления', '');
  $.ajax(`http://localhost:3000/users/${deleteUser}`, {
    method: 'Delete'
  }).done(function() { 
      // вот тут кусок кода, который нужен

      for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
           if(response[i].id == deleteUser) {
                response.splice(i, 1);
           }
       }
      usersDiv.innerHTML = '';
      for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
           usersDiv.innerHTML += 'id '+ response[i].id + '<br>' + response[i].name + '<br>' + response[i].email + '<br>' + '<br>';
      }
  });
});
```

То есть этим кодом я тебе показал, что нужно из уже существующего объекта `response` удалить нужный элемент с нужным id и все + полностью заново заполнить `userDiv`. Всю обработку нужно писать в `.done()` там ты можешь проверить, удалился ли этот элемент и потом уже обрабатывать и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо большое) понял как это делается